# How to add yii2 datepicker widget in external js file

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, gridview, datepicker, yii2

I want to add a `datepicker` while I add a new row in `gridview` using `js`.

Here I have added a new row:

```
$('.add').on("click",function()
      {
        var new_row="<tr id='"+id+"'>";
        new_row += visit_label;
        new_row += "<td style='width:20px;'></td>";
        new_row += "<td style='width:20px;'></td>";
        new_row += "<td style='width:20px;'></td>";
        new_row += "<td style='width:20px;'></td>";
        new_row += "<td style='width:20px;'></td>";

        new_row += "<td style='width:40px;padding-top:10px;'>";
        new_row += datepicker;
        new_row += "<button id='calendar_button' class='btn' type='button'><i class='icon-calendar'></i></button>";
        new_row += " <button class='btn' id='clearDates'>X</button></br>";
        new_row += " </td>";

        new_row += "<td style='width:60px;'><textarea id='comm' rows='3' style='width:90%;'></textarea></td>";
        new_row += "</tr>";
        $(this).closest('tr').after(new_row);
      });
```

I want to use a `datepicker widget` there just like I have used in the `gridview`.

```
echo DatePicker::widget([
        'name' => 'datepicker', 
        'value' => date('Mon DD YYYY'),
        'options' => ['placeholder' => ''],
        'clientOptions' => [
          'dateFormat' => 'Mon DD YYYY',
          'todayHighlight' => true,
          'autoSize'=>true,
          'showOn'=> "button",
        ]
      ]);
```

Now how can I use `datepicker` in my external JS file as my `bootstrap datepicker` is not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set:

```
$('#calendar_button').datepicker({
    format: 'mm/dd/yyyy',
    startDate: '-3d'
})
```

In your code:

```
    $('.add').on("click",function()
          {
            var new_row="<tr id='"+id+"'>";
            new_row += visit_label;
            new_row += "<td style='width:20px;'></td>";
            new_row += "<td style='width:20px;'></td>";
            new_row += "<td style='width:20px;'></td>";
            new_row += "<td style='width:20px;'></td>";
            new_row += "<td style='width:20px;'></td>";

            new_row += "<td style='width:40px;padding-top:10px;'>";

            new_row += "<button id='calendar_button' class='btn' type='button'><i class='icon-calendar'></i></button>";
            new_row += " <button class='btn' id='clearDates'>X</button></br>";
            new_row += " </td>";

            new_row += "<td style='width:60px;'><textarea id='comm' rows='3' style='width:90%;'></textarea></td>";
            new_row += "</tr>";
            $(this).closest('tr').after(new_row);
            $('#calendar_button').datepicker({
                format: 'mm/dd/yyyy',
                startDate: '-3d'
            })
          });
```

EDIT.

For get value use like that:

```
$("#calendar_button").datepicker(
{
    onSelect: function()
    { 
        var dateObject = $(this).datepicker('getDate'); 
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks! But how can I get the value from here?
I have modified 

`new_row += "<td style='width:40px;padding-top:10px;'><input id='calendar_input' style='width:90%;' readonly class='input-small' type='text'>";` 

Now how can I get the value of the datepicker inside the input textfield?

Comment: See `EDIT` case in my answer/